# jstree default checked state not working

Tags: jstree

I am trying to put default value for jstree check box,
the folder state to open is working but selected state to check is not working

here is the code.

```
$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({ 
         "core" : {"data":[{"dataParent":0,"id":30,"text":"Eyewear","state":{opened : true,checked : true},children : [{ "text" : "Child 2", state : { checked : true }}]}],
            "themes" : { "icons": false }
     },
    "plugins" : [ "checkbox" , "search" ],
});
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `checked` to `selected` as below. Check demo - [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/ZWQvEL).

```
{
    "data": [{
        "dataParent": 0,
        "id": 30,
        "text": "Eyewear",
        "state": {
            opened: true,
            selected: true
        },
        children: [{
            "text": "Child 2",
            state: {
                selected: true
            }
        }]
    }];
}
```